# How to get the screenshot of SVG on Safari?

Tags: javascript, svg, safari, screenshot, dom-to-image

I used dom-to-image to get the screenshot of svg, it worked successful on Chrome, but it will lost some svg layers on Safari. Is there any way to get screenshot of svg on Safari?

Comment: Just draw it into a canvas? Convert it to a data URL (`data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,${encodeURIComponent(svg.outerHTML)}`), make that the source of an image, then either draw that image directly to a similarly sized canvas or use the image directly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.